# Transitions between images are running slow on website (especially in Chrome), JavaScript issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've developed a website: 'www.malenemicha.com'. I've used HTML, CSS and JQuery. My problem is, that transitions between images are running slow. Both 'www.malenemicha.com' and 'www.malenemicha.com/portfolio' are running slow in all browsers - especially Chrome is running slow. Can anybody help me, so that browsing on this webpage can run faster?

Best regards

Comment: Javascript slow in Chrome? Sounds like you haven't done it right or it's not JS that's slowing you down.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a very non-specific question. I suggest you profile your application first to find out why its slow.

There are whole bunch of useful profilers out there, for front end, you could take the help of, to name a few:

- [Dyna trace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/Default.aspx)
- [Page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)

Comment: I already tried these tools. And it seems like everything is fine. But if you visit the website you will realize that it isn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, you problem is not with Javascript, it is something else, try profiling your backend code.